# Calculated fields not working when using update command on |Excel

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am using `OleDb` library to update an existing `Excel Sheet` my code as follows

```
   string conStr = "";
        //getting the path of the file     
        string path = "file path";
        //connection string for that file which extantion is .xlsx    
        conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=False;HDR=Yes;\"";

        //Process myProcess = Process.Start(path);

        //Providing connection    
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        //checking that connection state is closed or not if closed the     
        //open the connection    
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            //making query    
            string query = "Update [Sheet1$] set name = 'Mohamed', Email =  'dev.msalah' , [Basic Salary] = 10 ,[Variable Salary] = 20 where ID = " + i;


            //create command object    
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
```

in `Excel sheet` i used a table in order to create `Calculated Field`

if used the above code without `Process.Start` everything is working fine and fast except calculated fields. its not working even when i opened the file and force calculation

if I used `Process.Start` the excel sheet opens and calculated fields calculated successfully but with the following issues:

1. the processing time is large
2. the sheet is not saved after processing finished

any advice to avoid and fix this issue?

Comment: Please explain how `Process.Start` would be used in conjunction with your code.

Comment: if you notice after connection string i added `Process.Start`. i am using this to open the excel program to execute my code